# How to select all entries without duplicates based chosen value from a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm kinda new here, and this is my first question. Pardon my inexperience. I don't know if this is the right way to do this. But I'm open for suggestions.

I have a table, application

[image: Table Application]

I want to be able to select all no duplicate positions:

1. that an applicant has applied to
2. Including positions with no applicants yet
3. positions not applied to by the applicant even if it is applied to by other applicants, it doesn't matter which other applicant

So result would be when dynamically selecting the applicant,
If I choose applicant 1, the result should be:

[image: Result 1]

If I choose applicant 2, the result should be:

[image: Result 2]

I tried using Except Set operations. Not quite there yet. This is in PostgreSQL by the way. I hope I'm making sense. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to have one result row per `position`, and if there are several rows for one `position`, you'd prefer the one with a certain applicant.

That could be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (position)
       position, applicant
FROM atable
ORDER BY position, (applicant = 2) DESC;
```

That strange `ORDER BY` clause relies upon `FALSE < TRUE` for boolean values.